# getting this error in my code, Failed to fetch at sendData (form.js:42:5)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, firebase

Screenshot of error:

[image: Error itself here - screenshot]

So, basically i'm getting this weird error in my java Script file, called: Failed to fetch
at sendData
and i don't know quite what is the error, i cant save nothing to my database cause of this error

here's the code from the form.js :

```
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

// select inputs

const SubmitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');

const name = document.querySelector('#name');

const email = document.querySelector('#email');

const password = document.querySelector('#password');

const number = document.querySelector('#number');

const tac = document.querySelector('#terms-and-cond');

const notification = document.querySelector('#notification');

SubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (name.value.length < 3) {

    showAlert('name must be 3 letters long');

  } else if (!email.value.length) {

    showAlert('enter your email');

  } else if (password.value.length < 8) {

    showAlert('password should be 8 letters long');

  } else if (!number.value.length) {

    showAlert('enter your phone number');

  } else if (!Number(number.value) || number.value.length < 10) {

    showAlert('invalid number, please enter a valid one');

  } else if (!tac.checked) {

    showAlert('you must agree to our terms and conditions')

  } else {

    // submeter o form

    loader.style.display = 'block';

    sendData('/signup', {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value,
      number: number.value,
      tac: tac.checked,
      notification: notification.checked,
      seller: false
    })
  }
})

// send data function

const sendData = (path, data) => {

  fetch(path, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((res) => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      processData(response);
    })
}

const processData = (data) => {
  loader.style.display = null;
  if (data.alert) {
    showAlert(data.alert);
  }
}

// alert funcionalidade

const showAlert = (msg) => {

  let alertBox = document.querySelector('.alert-box');
  let alertMsg = document.querySelector('.alert-msg');
  alertMsg.innerHTML = msg;
  alertBox.classList.add('show');
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertBox.classList.remove('show');
  }, 3000);
}
```

with this i always get the same error, it doesn't save the users to the database, and its kinda irritating. i would like help for this type of error as soon as possible. this for a school project and time is coming short...

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that error from browser console? Usually there are some more details than just `Failed to fetch`. Also how is this related to Firebase?

Comment: yes i can, but as i said, its not a firebase error, its from the java code itself. my apologies. im going to send now a screenshot of that error from browser console

Comment: Do you have your server running at port 3000? The error says it cannot connect to that.

Comment: yes i do, port 3000

Comment: @Dharmaraj u have any suggestions on what i should do?

Comment: Can you try the POST request using [Postman](https://postman.com) ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj can u teach me on discord? please, i am really struggling here... here is my discord tag h1zas#5450

Comment: It might be best to provide any more details (like how is your server running and then updating Firebase) here so it'll be useful for anyone else as well. You can join the Discord server linked in my profile if want to chat on Discord. Happy to help.

Comment: OP has incorrect import of `bcrypt` that was crashing the server and hence the error. Marking as typo.